# Does $\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{n 2^{n} } {4^n +(-1)^n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine if $\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{n 2^{n} } {4^n +(-1)^n}$ converges.

By root test, we have that:

$\lim |(\frac{n 2^{n} } {4^n +(-1)^n})|^{1/n} = \lim \frac{n^{1/n}2} {3}$

And since the exponent 1/n is increasing faster than n, we have that the series converges to 0?

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}[\frac{n2^n}{4^n+(-1)^n}]^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{2}{3}\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Instead, use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}[1+(-1)^n4^{-n}]^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ to get
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[\frac{n2^n}{4^n+(-1)^n}\Big]^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}{[1+(-1)^n4^{-n}]^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Since $\frac{1}{2}<1$, the series converges by the root test. The limit comparison test would also work nicely for this series.

Comment: Probably something I'm overlooking, but how did you get from $4^n + (-1)^n$ in the denominator to $[1 + (-1)^n 4^{-n}]$? And how ddi we end up with $\frac{1}{2}$ if we had $2^n$ in the numerator?

Comment: I factored $2^n$ out of the numerator and $4^n$ out of the denominator, which simplified to $(\frac{2}{4})^n=(\frac{1}{2})^n$, and the $n$th power was cancelled by the $n$th root.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>3$, $0<u_n={{n2^n}\over{4^n+(-1)^n}}$.

${{u_{n+1}}\over u_n}={{(n+1)2^{n+1}(4^n-(-1)^n)}\over{n2^n(4^{n+1}-(-1)^n)}}$=

${1\over 2}{{n+1}\over n}$ ${{1-{(-1)^n\over 4^n}}\over {1-{(-1)^n\over 4^{n+1}}}}$.

$lim_n{u_{n+1}\over u_n}=1/2$ so it converges.